# Can $\text{Aut}(L^s_K/K)$ and $\text{Aut}(L/K)$ be canonically identified?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am reading a Galois theory textbook. The following is a point that I don't understand.

Suppose that $L/K$ is a finite normal extension with $\text{Aut}(L/K)$. Denote by $L^s_K$ the set $\{x\in L:x~\text{is separable over}~K\}$. Then, the author said that $\text{Aut}(L^s_K/K)$ and $\text{Aut}(L/K)$ can be canonically identified.

What does "canonically identified" mean? I myself think that it would mean if I pick any map from $\text{Aut}(L^s_K/K)$, then we can extend it uniquely to be in $\text{Aut}(L/K)$ and also vice versa in terms of restriction. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your interpretation is correct. If $\alpha \in L$ in not separable then its minimal polynomial is $f(x^{p^e})$ (where $p=char(K)$)for some $e$ and $f(x)$ is separable. So $\alpha^{p^e}\in L^s$ has an image under a given automorphism, which is another root of $f(x)$, then, since $L$ is normal, it it clear there is exactly one way to extent the automorphism.

Comment: I am so sorry. It is not clear for me. If I pick $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(L^s_K/K)$, then $\sigma(\alpha^{p^e})\in L^s_K$.  Then, how should I go on?

Comment: Lets say $\beta=\sigma(\alpha^{p^e})$ then $\alpha$ should be mapped to the unique solution to $x^{p^e}-\beta=0$.